# Any good libraries for Cropping Images in Android on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, image, bitmap, crop

I need to crop android images. Basically, I need to pick an image from the Gallery and crop it. I am using Eclipse. I haven't made the switch to Gradle. The present library that I am using is not reliable

```
import eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage;
```

Some of my users are having issues in that when they try to crop the image behaves strangely and sometimes disappears entirely. So I need something that is much more reliable. I was going to try https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop but I don't know how to translate Gradle to Eclipse. Thanks for any help on this issue.

Comment: I need it to work with API level 11 and up

Comment: Have you found any library for eclipse ?

Answer (score 3):

See this libs:

1. [CropImageView](https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView)
2. [Cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper)
3. [Android-Crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)
4. [Cropimage](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage)

**Edited**:

to use `CropImageView` copy to your project the following files.

[CropImageView.java](https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView/blob/master/cropimageview/src/main/java/com/cesards/cropimageview/CropImageView.java)

[attrs.xml](https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView/blob/master/cropimageview/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml)

You can do this with the other libs also copy the necessary parts into your project.

Comment: thanks but I don't know how to use these projects in eclipse. They are all gradle.

Comment: I have been trying. But the library projects do not have a jar file. So I have to load them into eclipse. How might I do that since they too are for Gradle?

Comment: The gradle is a dependencies manager among other things, an eclipse of the Android project can be imported into the Android Studio, then you can manually import a Android Studio project in Eclipse, just pick up the "res" folder and "java" files. if the project in the Android Studio has dependencies you will have to look for the jar.