# Getting exception for image cropping using intent in android lollipop version. How to crop an image using crop intent in above 5.0 versions?

Tags: android, image

I have the following code for cropping images. It's working perfectly in android version 4 or OS Kitkat, but its not working on Android version 5 or OS Lollipop.

I have searched in google but I didn't find perfect answer.

//Cropping image using intent

```
private void doCrop() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    final ArrayList<CropOptionAdapter.CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOptionAdapter.CropOption>();
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    int size = list.size();
    //if no crop applications are available return the process
    if (size == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        if (size > 0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            context.startActivityForResult(i, CROP_PHOTO_SELECTED);
        }
    }
}
```

In above method i am calling cropping intent, and handling result in onActivityResult(). Below 5.0 versions I am getting crop image result datam But in above 5.0.1 versions I am getting data as null.
Below is my onActivityResult().

//OnActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTION_PHOTO:
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            case CROP_PHOTO_SELECTED:
                    myPhotoCaptureOnResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

//Cropping image based on requestcode

```
public void myPhotoCaptureOnResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTION_PHOTO: {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    //setting image from singleton class which is store at time of capture in PhoneIntentActivity
                    if (Singleton.getSingletonObj().getBitmap() != null) {
                        mCapture_photo.setImageBitmap(Singleton.getSingletonObj().getBitmap());
                        mCapture_photo.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // getting image uri from sharedpreferences
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.parse(context.getSharedPreferences(StringUtils.APP_PREFFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(StringUtils.IMAGE_URI_KEY, null));

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        doCrop();
                    } else {
                        // showing toast when unable to capture the image
                        Debug.toastValid(context, "Unable to Capture Image Please Try again ...");
                    }
                }
                break;

            case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data.getData() != null) {
                        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                        doCrop();
                    } else {
                        // showing toast when unable to capture the image
                        Debug.toastValid(context, "Unable to Capture Image Please Try again ...");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case CROP_PHOTO_SELECTED:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    if (extras != null) {
                        //getting the photo data from the crop intent
                        Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        if (photo != null) {
                            mResizedBitMap = getResizedBitmap(photo, newHeight, newWidth);
                            Singleton.getSingletonObj().setBitmap(mResizedBitMap);
                            setBitMap(mResizedBitMap);
                            mCapture_photo.setImageBitmap(Singleton.getSingletonObj().getBitmap());
                            mCapture_photo.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Below is my Logcat....

```
 10-15 14:41:06.250    8332-8332/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.apps.photos, PID: 8332
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.photoeditor.intents.EditActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No 'output' extra specified and can not save to specified inputUri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F2236/ACTUAL/1186776521
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1365)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No 'output' extra specified and can not save to specified inputUri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F2236/ACTUAL/1186776521
        at com.google.android.apps.photos.photoeditor.intents.EditActivity.a(PG:13312)
        at gpy.a(PG:88)
        at mgf.a(PG:5197)
        at mgg.a(PG:169)
        at mgf.W_(PG:4114)
        at ofw.a(PG:213)
        at oft.a(PG:98)
        at oft.l(PG:209)
        at ogs.onResume(PG:68)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3006)
```

Comment: check this libraries out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190328/any-good-libraries-for-cropping-images-in-android-on-eclipse

Comment: I have to crop an image with intent cropping not with custom cropping. Those links are related to custom cropping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user).

Referenced from [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) on Android Developers [Website](https://developer.android.com/index.html).

`ACTION_CROP` launches an "other application" that supports cropping, and passes it the URI of the file to crop. If that file is in internal storage, it is not directly accessible to the cropping application.

Using a `[FileProvider][1]` to provide an internal file to other apps requires some configuration. Referenced From [Setting Up File Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) on Android Developers [Website](https://developer.android.com/index.html).

For more information and ideal solution that worked for me on Android 5.1.1, Please see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30961919/3140227).

Comment: You just have to replace "providedUri" to "imageUri" of your selected image in this `cropIntent.setDataAndType(providedUri, "image/*");`

Comment: check if your camera returned image is not `null`.

Comment: Captured image is not null, an Intent crop result is returning null.

Comment: have you implemented as solution provided in the link? with `path.xml` and 'AndroidManifest' code.

Answer (score 0):

On Lollipop, the cropped image is returned as a String reference to a uri in the result data action value rather than the extras part. For example:

```
final String action = data.getAction();
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(action)
```